# What is the significance of the largest/ smallest eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I want to know what is the significance or importance of the largest and smallest eigenvalue in graph analysis (social network).

I understood how eigenvectors helps to find the centrality of the nodes in graph. But I'm wondering how the smallest and largest eigenvalues are useful in graph analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Laplacian of a graph can give a complete description of graph topology (it is the same as knowing the weight matrix.).

For instance, $0$ eigenvalues show the number of isolated subgraphs and eigenvectors of these $0$ eigenvalues are constant through the subgraphs.

As eigenvalues increase corresponding eigenvectors (localized to different subgraphs) start to have more high-frequency components.

In fact, Graph Signal Processing people do use eigenvectors as a Graph Fourier Transform basis.

In short, eigenvectors corresponding to small eigenvalues tend to include low-frequency components of the graph topology while large eigenvalues tend to correspond to fast-changing components of the topology.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If I have n nodes in my graph, will I get n eigen values, so that it represents the weight of nodes?

Comment: If you have n nodes you will have n eigenvalues but I am not sure that I follow the second part. You cannot infer much only by eigenvalues (there are infinitely many graphs with same eigenvalues but with different eigenvectors). Connected component number from $0$ eigenvalues is one of few things you can directly infer.

Comment: I'm new to applying this eigen concepts. could you tell me how eigen vectors and eigen values influencing nodes centrality. As far I know centrality weight based on eigen vectors. As I understood your question, eigen values also influencing the weight. can you clear me out in this?

Comment: Eigenvalues give some hints on the topology but do not specify it by themselves only. Shortly, eigenvalues affect weights but do not specify them 1-1

Comment: thanks for the answer and your explanation

Comment: Your statement "it is the same as knowing the weight matrix" is - _as you commented yourself_ - not accurate.  The high-level topology can be ascertained but the weights contain irreducible details.

Comment: @javadba I find your comment not accurate, and this is not to be pity, but what is stated is the following: "Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Laplacian of a graph can give a complete description of graph topology (it is the same as knowing the weight matrix.)." This true statement is quite trivial as you may obtain a matrix (Laplacian in this case) from its matrix of eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues, right? Additionally, if there are no self loops then you can find the weight matrix uniquely from its Laplacian. So please do elaborate, what is inaccurate here.

Comment: Your answer is close but you might incorporate _your own_ comment into it:  _Eigenvalues give some hints on the topology but do not specify it by themselves only. Shortly, eigenvalues affect weights but do not specify them 1-1 –_

Comment: @javadba I am sorry but it is not close but a correct statement. "Eigenvalues AND(!) eigenvectors of Laplacian" maybe you are mistaking AND and OR. What I also added is correct as well: you can have any set of orthonormal eigenvectors if it is not given.

Comment: Maybe go through your comments and add to your answer: I'm trying to follow but your statements are self inconsistent.

Comment: This has become something quite unproductive and unrelated to the question. Feel free interpret what I have shared in any manner you wish. I believe if you have further problems you may ask a question.